# If a linear ODE system has a solution that tends to zero, it also has an unbounded solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

> $a:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continous and bounded and
>   $$x'(t)\ =\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\-a(t)&0\end{matrix}\right) \ x(t)$$ has a non-zero solution like $y(t)$ such that $\lim_{t \to \infty} y(t)=0$.

Show that this equation has an unbounded solution on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: is $a$ a function of $t$, this means $a=a(t)$?

Comment: Dr.Sonnhard Graubner:yes

Comment: Hint: pick a solution $z$ independent of $y$, and consider the Wronskian of $y$ and $z$. Also,   try [asking better questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$. The system can be written as he second order linear equation
$$
x_1''+a(t)\,x_1=0.
$$
We know that it has a solution $y_1$ with $\lim_{t\to\infty}y_1(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}y_1'(t)=0$. To find another solution let $x_1=z\,y_1$. Then
$$
z''\,y_1+2\,z'\,y_1'+z\,y_1''-a\,z\,y_1=0\implies \frac{z''}{z'}=-2\,\frac{y_1'}{y_1}\implies z'=\frac{C}{y_1^2}.\tag{1}
$$
Thus
$$
x_1(t)=y_1(t)\int_0^t\frac{ds}{(y_1(s))^2}
$$
is a solution of equation (1) (and the firs component of ta solution of the system.) I leave it to you to show that $\lim_{t\to\infty}x_1(t)=\infty$.